# Правильно отобразить response полученный c сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Делаю запрос `get` на сервер и получаю ответ в формате json. `response.data` выглядит так: `[ { "name": "mike", "password": "2345", "old": "12" }, { "name": "5c251688a3df283bb8630cc6", "password": "2345", "old": "12"}, { "name": "John", "password": "2345", "old": "20" ]`.Как вывести к примеру все имена, или все пароли и тд. Вот сам метод:

```
 getPerson: function() {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/names'
      axios.get(url, {
        dataType: 'json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:8080',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE' })
        .then(response => {
          return (this.info = response.data)
        })
```

Comment: в чем проблема тпа

Comment: @Санитариум, К примеру, есть поле `name`, туда нужно вывести все имена из полученного `response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так что ли

```
    var result = {
      names: []
    };
    response.data.map(v => {
       result.names.push(v.name);
    })


 var result = {
      names: [
         'mike', 
         '5c251688a3df283bb8630cc6',
         'John'
      ]
    };
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно было. А если быть точнее, то забыл что можно было использовать `map`, помогло мне `map(v => {
       result.names.push(v.name)`